# Zoom video using ffmpeg commands

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Is it possible to zoom a video and save it using ffmpeg commands?

I searched a lot but I did not find any solution.

Comment: Yes it is possible to zoom. Does that help? Your questions are too vague. They cannot be answered unless you are more specific.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Zooming is a two step process. You want to:

1. Scale the video by a factor of your choice.
2. Crop the video back to its original size.

That'd look something like this, e.g. to zoom in with a factor of 2, assuming an input video of 1280×720 pixels:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=2*iw:-1, crop=iw/2:ih/2" output.mp4
```

Of course, you can change the factor here. The `-1` means that the height will be set automatically.

You can use two additional parameters for the `crop` filter to set the position of the cropping window.

Have a look at the [x264 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) if you need to change the output quality (it will be reduced compared to the original, of course).

Comment: `scale=2*iw:-1,crop=iw/2:ih/2` could be used for 2x zoom.

Comment: Slhck thanks for ypur reply. That command is working perfectly, but where can I change the amount of zooming, and how can I use this command for zoo out?.

Comment: @Gururaj I mentioned that in my example the factor would be 2, so you simply have to choose another factor. I'm not sure if zooming out is that easily accomplished with a factor between 0 and 1. I can't try it now.

Comment: slhck I am getting some bars on video after zooming.

Comment: @Gururaj If there's an issue with the command, you should probably post a new question, mention exactly what command you're using, and show the full, uncut command line output. Note that if you want to zoom out you have to `scale` down first and then `pad` the output.