# How do I zoom in and save a video using VLC media player?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, video-editing

So I have a video, I click "Video" -> "Zoom" -> "Double", then try to convert it using the video magnify/zoom filter, but it just ends up zoomed in at the top corner, i.e not where it was when watching in the VLC player (compare the video in standard windows media player). How can I properly zoom in and save the video?

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/q/684747/141595) asks about the same issue, but then using ffmpeg. Would that help?