# ffmpeg: How to zoom a video for few seconds in particular area?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, zoom

How to just zoom some video area for n seconds? Without any fade in/out movements? The only parameters I should pass are: start time in seconds, stop time or duration, center point and frame dimensions, and zoom level. This can overlay the original, not zoomed area.

Have no code for now, because don't know how to start it, but I'll develop it now.

Comment: I often wonder why people struggle with command-line video solutions when one of the world's finest video editing suites is available ***free*** for personal use. [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/) - Mac, Win & Nix.

Comment: @Tetsujin I use such tools. Questions are for learning. Command-line solutions use least resources and least bugs as well. Different programs are also hard to learn sometimes, and c-line is fastest - especially if you invest your time to get some knowledge. And many programs are now corporate products, so you are implicitly forced to "watch" somewhere.

Comment: `[0]crop=400:400:480:20, scale=iw*1.5:ih*1.5[c]; [0][c]overlay=380:-80: enable='between(t,1,3)'` calculate position: 480-(400*1.5-400)/2=380, 20-(400*1.5-400)/2=-80

Answer (score 2):

Since each step is explained better in other answers I'll just link them in this post:

1. Slice the video into N parts using [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212518).
2. Then use [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/684887/1689619) to zoom required part(s).
3. Merge all parts back in order using [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1230097/1689619) (you can actually use it in step 1 too).

Comment: That's what I just did as overcome. Maybe it's not what I wanted, because I tried to apply zoomed overlay from current frame and do it at once, but failed. Anyway your answer is worth upvoting. Very interesting answers indeed.